# I can't make commits with my original account

Tags: git, github, github-for-mac

I installed `git` my MacBook Pro and built a basic iOS project and then made commits to the repository.

But, now when I'm trying to trace the commits that I made, it displays my full name instead of my username on the commits and I can't click to check what is wrong with it.

It is showing the commits on the repository but when I view my commits for the day, it is showing nothing on my timeline.

[image: Github commits screenshot]

[image: Github profile view commits]

This has never happened with me on Git before. Please help, I'm really confused. What did I do wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This has happened to me as well. This usually happens if your git has a different `user.email` & `user.name` set than your remote(GitHub) account. When you commit from your local machine, GitHub sees a different person committing rather you.

Please open your command line and type `git config -l`. This will show you what email id and name you are using. Like this:

```
$ git config -l
user.email=myemail@email.com
user.name=Debadipti Patra
```

Check if this matches with your GitHub account. If not change the global value entering this:

```
$ git config --global user.email "you email"
$ git config --global user.name "you name"
```

and confirm by `$ git config -l`

Try committing to your repository. Hopefully that works. But unfortunately, that don't fix your past commits, those will still not be there on your timeline.

Please share if it did work. It helps other users as well.

Comment: Thanks! It worked. Although what I don't understand is how was I able to make commits if I was not able to use my original `username`? Do you know why it happened or why was I still able to make commits to it?

Comment: As far as I know, you were still able to make commits from your local machine which have a different email ID set (which git asks when first commit a change and you had set a different email ID than your GitHub email ID), because you are committing through your credentials (your GitHub username and passwords). Anyone having your GitHub credentials and the remote link to your git repository can commit to your Git repository, at least I am guessing it.